# Taking Same Worksheet from a Folder of xlsm Files with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm new to pandas/python and Ive come up with the following code to extract data from a specific part of a worksheet.

```
import openpyxl as xl
import pandas as pd

rows_with_data = [34,37,38,39,44,45,46,47,48,49, 50,54,55,57,58,59,60,62,63,64,65,66,70,71,72,76,77, 78,79,80,81,82,83,84,88,89,90,91,92]

path = r'XXX'
xpath = input('XXX') 
file = r'**.xlsm'
xfile = input('Change file name, current is ' + file + ' :')
sheetname = r'Summary'

wb = xl.load_workbook(filename = xpath + '\\' +file, data_only = True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname)

rows = len(rows_with_data)
line_items = []
for i in range(rows) :
    line_items.append(sheet.cell(row = rows_with_data[i], column = 13).value)

period = []
for col in range(17,35):
    period.append(sheet.cell(row = 20, column = col).value)

print(line_items)

vals = []
x = []
for i in range(rows):
    if i != 0:
        vals.append(x)
        x = []
    for col in range(17,35):

        x.append(sheet.cell(row = rows_with_data[i], column = col).value)


vals.append(x)      
all_values = {}
all_values['Period'] = period
for i in range(rows):
    print(line_items[i])   
    all_values[line_items[i]] = vals[i]

print(all_values)

period_review = input('Enter a period (i.e. 2002): ')
item = input('Enter a period (i.e. XXX): ') 

time = period.index(period_review)
display_item = str(all_values[item][time])
print(item + ' for ' + period_review + " is " + display_item)

Summary_Dataframe = pd.DataFrame(all_values)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xpath + '\\' + 'values.xlsx')
Summary_Dataframe.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

I have the same worksheet (summary results) across a library of 60 xlsm files and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to iterate this across the entire folder of files.  I also want change this from extracting specific rows to taking the entire "Summary" worksheet, pasting it to the new file and naming the worksheet by its filename ("Experiment_A") when pasted to the new excel file.  Any advice?

Comment: I don't think you need to use pandas in this at all but please simplify the question.

Comment: the code i came up with initially was to extract a range within the sheet.  rather than just take a subset of the sheet, i am looking to see how to extract an entire sheet and also looping across a folder of 60 xlsm files.

Answer (score 0):

I was having hard time to read your code to understand that what you want to do finally. **So it is just an advice not a solution.** You can iterate through all files in the folder using `os` then read the files in to one dataframe then save the single big data frame in to csv. I usually avoid excel but I guess you need the excel conversion. In the example below I have read all txt file from a directory put them in to dataframe list then store the big data frame as json. You can also store it as excel/csv.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def process_data():
    # input file path in 2 part in case it is very long
    input_path_1 = r'\\path\to\the\folder'
    input_path_2 = r'\second\part\of\the\path'
    # adding the all file path
    file_path = input_path_1 + input_path_2
    # listing all file in the file folder
    file_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(file_path))
    # selecting only the .txt files in to a list object
    file_list = [file_name for file_name in file_list if '.txt' in file_name]
    # selecting the fields we need
    field_names = ['country', 'ticket_id']
    # defining a list to put all the datafremes in one list
    pd_list = []
    inserted_files = []
    # looping over txt files and storing in to database
    for file_name in file_list:
      # creating the file path to read the file
      file_path_ = file_path + '\\' + file_name
      df_ = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(file_path_), sep='\t', usecols=field_names)
      # converting the datetime to date
      # few internal data transformation example before writting
      df_['sent_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_['sent_date'])
      df_['sent_date'] = df_['sent_date'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')
      # adding each dataframe to the list
      pd_list.append(df_)
      # adding file name to the inserted list to print later
      inserted_files.append(file_name)
    print(inserted_files)
    # sql like union all dataframes and create a single data source
    df_ = pd.concat(pd_list)

    output_path_1 = r'\\path\to\output'
    output_path_2 = r'\path\to\output'
    output_path = output_path_1 + output_path_2
    # put the file name
    file_name = 'xyz.json'
    # adding the day the file processed
    df_['etl_run_time'] = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    # write file to json
    df_.to_json(os.path.join(output_path, file_name), orient='records')
    return print('Data Stored as json successfully')

process_data()
```

Comment: thanks for trying to read through my code and replying.  i am looking to take one sheet from a group of files and copy/paste them into excel.  since i am working with others, im stuck with excel.

Comment: So still you can use the first part to iterate through all files in the folder using os and then apply something according to your need.